# How to recover South from flushing db

Tags: django, postgresql, django-south

I bulk loaded some data into my Postgresql db, only to realize all of it was a bit wrong. Keen to rectify this I **flushed** the db in order to reload the correct data.

Data reloaded, I made a change to a model and applied the normal `./manage.py schemamigration app --auto`, and then `./manage.py migrate app` (which had been working up to this point).

At this point I started getting the error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: relation "app_model" already exists
```

And the traceback appeared to be calling the initial migration file 001. So I think the answer is to do something like:

```
./manage.py migrate app 0005 --fake
```

Where the current migration that I'm looking to apply is 0006 (i.e. this is where the migrations began failing), and then the south database within postgres should be back where it was before I foolishly flushed it. At this point I should be able to

```
./manage.py migrate app
```

Can someone tell me that this approach is correct? Or if not, what the correct approach is?

Comment: It is hard to say for sure, but from what you describe it sounds like you are taking the right approach. To be sure, can you create a copy of your database schema and test on that first?

Comment: you could alsy try creating a new database (+change db name in settings.py) and running syncdb + migrate

Comment: @StephenEmslie, this is exactly the kind of advice I needed, I was on the right track and being able to make a 'throwaway' database and test the migrations on it as specified was very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `python manage.py migrate app --fake` 
do a `python manage.py schemamigration app --auto`
and then do a `python manage.py migrate app`

Answer (score 0):

You can also make it more general:

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py flush
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

This will recover all the south history after flush